# Using package settings to enable/disable keybindings (as part of context list in keybindings)

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

is it possible to use settings defined in a package setting file as part of keybindings "context" argument? Below is an (abbreviated) example from the default keybindings files. This keybinding is only valid when the setting `auto_indent` is true. `auto_indent` is part of the main preferences. I have a `my_package.sublime-settings` file in my package and would like to add keybindings that only work when a certain setting is true (let's say the `use_keys` setting defined in `my_package.sublime-settings`). How does that work? `setting.use_keys` doesn't work and probably would be problematic because it overwrites default settings. `setting.my_package.use_keys` doesn't work either. Any way to do this?

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "reindent", "context":
   [
      { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
      ...
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an `on_query_context` event listener and use your own settings. See the API docs for more information on this method. If you don't want to create your own on_query_context method, you can create a `Preferences.sublime-settings` file in your package. The settings will be merged and applied to the view. Just be sure to note that to toggle the behavior, the users need to add an override in User/Preferences.sublime-settings.